# Retrieving a number at a time from a string - PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project of mine and came across an interesting problem.  Lets say you have a string that contains `5,5689, 1546,572` and with this string, lets say I want to separate each of the numbers separated by a comma and store them into a database individually.

For instance, it would take `5` and store that into the database.  Than it would take `5689` and store that into the database.

How would you ladies and gentlemen go about this?

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you do not have problems to save the information in the bank .. but about breaking comma, u can use the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
explode(',', $string);
```

and now you have this array:

```
0 => 5
1 => 5689
2 => 1546
3 => 572
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

From manual: `Returns an array of strings created by splitting the string parameter on boundaries formed by the delimite`

Example:

```
$number = '5,5689,1546,572';
$numberArray = explode(',',$number);
echo numberArray[0];//Output: 5
echo numberArray[1];//Output: 5689 
echo numberArray[2];//Output: 1546 
echo numberArray[3];//Output: 572
```

Or use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop over the new array

```
 foreach($numberArray as $key => $value){
    echo $value.'<br>';
 }
```

**Output:**

5

5689

1546

572